# How to include 2 single quotes in a variable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, single-quotes

Below line is returning me the value with single quote.

```
set @SearchStr2= upper(QUOTENAME('%''' + @SearchStr + '''%','''') )COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

Actual Output : '%'NM'%'

Expected Output : '%''NM''%' -- Need 2 single quotes before and after %

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are targeting.  Assuming your current code's @SearchStr = 'NM'.  Your current code should return your "Expected Output".

If that isn't what you're expecting, just add more single quotes till you get what you want.

Example:

```
SELECT UPPER(QUOTENAME('''%''' + 'NM' + '''%''','''') )COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

I added more 2x single quotes before and after the %'s and that added an additional single quote on the return screen.  `'''%''NM''%'''`